# Datanode getting dead ambari hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, ambari

I have setup hadoop cluster using `ambari 1.7` I'm facing one weired problem. At first time data nodes gets started but automatically within fraction of second it goes dead. When I try to restart datanode It's not starting. Please help me to resolve this issue.
 Log for restarting datanode as follows

```
2015-01-26 17:58:02,233 - Error while executing command 'start':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 123, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/HDFS/package/scripts/datanode.py", line 37, in start
    datanode(action="start")
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/HDFS/package/scripts/hdfs_datanode.py", line 55, in datanode
    create_log_dir=True
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.0.6/services/HDFS/package/scripts/utils.py", line 102, in service
    not_if=service_is_up
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 149, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 115, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 241, in action_run
    raise ex
Fail: Execution of 'ulimit -c unlimited;  su -s /bin/bash - hdfs -c 'export HADOOP_LIBEXEC_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/libexec && /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /etc/hadoop/conf start datanode'' returned 1. stdin: is not a tty
starting datanode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-node1.out
```

I have a similiar problem after restarting my hadoop cluster. And here is my log file from /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-master.hadoopcluster.out

```
ulimit -a for user hdfs
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 62510
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 128000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 65536
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: What's the error in the datanode's log file? The log file is probably at: /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-datanode-<insert hostname here>.log

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolve the problem （It is not a perfect solution but I put it here for you reference）.

After a few attempts and google search, I release it might be caused by the inconsistency between name node and data node.

So I deleted the entire HDFS directory from each data node. The location of your data node directory can be viewed from `hdfs-site.xml`.

After that, I format the namenode via command `hadoop namenode -format`

By then, I was able to launch the data nodes but failed to start the namenode.

Finally, I deleted the name node directory from my master machine and restart the entire cluster.

Now it works fine but I inevitably lost my origin data in the old HDFS.